# qt error: multiple definition of `Protocol::Protocol()'

Tags: c++, qt

i write a class in Protocal.h file.

```
#ifndef PROTOCOL_H
#define PROTOCOL_H

class Protocol{
public:
    Protocol();

    void analyse();
};

Protocol::Protocol() {}

void Protocol::analyse() {
}

#endif // PROTOCOL_H
```

in sinffer.h file, i use this header file 
[image]

when i build the project, there has some error, i don't why.
[image: error message image]

and in my .pro file
[image]

there only writes protocol.h file once.

Comment: Write all definitions of member functions including constructors and destructor in cpp file, or define them in the class. Do not define them in header file (outside of the class).

Comment: @Artur Pyszczuk yes, i try it just now,  define member functions in header file, and write function body in cpp file, then it's ok, thank you very much.

Comment: Just a tiny nit-picker here, but please fix "protocal" to "protocol". :)

Comment: @Bugfinger, haha, i have corrected it, thank you.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, and twice as that? OP took time and effort to make a question with code, and pictures. [Guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) say "Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.", which this is clearly not.

Comment: @coyotte508 - I'll be careful, thank you for reminding me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define body of the Protocol contructor using the following ways:

## In the class definition (implicit inline)

```
 // protocol.h    
 class Protocol {
 public:
    Protocol() {
      // in the class definition
    }
    ...
 };
```

## Explicit inline

```
 // protocol.h    
 class Protocol {
 public:
    Protocol();
    ...
 };
 // 
 inline Protocol::Protocol() {
 // inline prevents double definition error when you include protocol.h
 }
```

## Put in cpp file

```
 // protocol.h    
 class Protocol {
 public:
    Protocol();
    ...
 };
 // protocol.cpp
 #include "protocol.h"
 Protocol::Protocol() {
 }
```

Comment: thank you very much, i understand it through your code.